# Why isnt my audio working on a webpage that im working on, which is not live yet

Tags: html

Im working on a webpage, and im trying to have an audio file play from soundcloud, but it doesnt seem to work. it works if the src is from my computer but not from the soundcloud website.

```
<audio controls autoplay loop>

<source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mp3">

<a href="https://soundcloud.com/grixis/peacetreaty-change-grixis">

</audio>
```

ive also tried the following below:

```
<audio controls autoplay loop>

<source src="https://soundcloud.com/grixis/peacetreaty-change-grixis" type="audio/mp3">

</audio>
```

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript

Answer (score 0):

You are providing a soundcloud link, which is a HTML page. Try providing a mp3 link instead.
If you need the ability to play from soundcloud, try embedding their player.

https://soundcloud.com/pages/embed